# how to round up to the next x20 number with php?

Tags: php

I know ceil, which will round 15.1 to 16 and 31.2 to 32.
But how to round up to the next x20 number? like 15.1 to 20 and 31,2 to 40?

Is needed to make sensefull labels for the y-axis of a chart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

divide by 20 and use ceil, then multiply by 20

Answer (score 3):

Try this (works in JavaScript):

```
$result = 20 * ceil($input / 20);
```

Here, we're rounding to `20`. To round to other numbers, simply replace `20` with whatever base you want. The documentation for `ceil()` can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php).

A function that does the same:

```
function roundTo($value, $base)
{
    return $base * ceil($value / $base);
}
```

---

As a small aside, if you want to round *to the nearest* base, instead of rounding *up*, use [`round()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) instead of `ceil()`.

Comment: Great solution as long as you don't want `9=0` and `15=20` (where values between round just like a decimal point would). The above makes `0=20` and `1-20=20` then `21=40`

Answer (score 2):

Or you could use modulus:

```
echo round($a + 20 - ($a % 20));
```

Comment: You should underline the fact that $a must be already ceiled in this formula.

Comment: @samura If `$a = 19.9` then the result would be 21.

Answer (score 2):

If you want "mid-range" values to round more, you can use [the following](http://www.ideone.com/pa8AU).

```
function roundTo($n,$i = 1){
  $r = $n % $i;
  $d = round(($n - $r * $i) / $i);
  return $r * $i + $d * $i;
}

for ($a = 0; $a < 100; $a++){
  printf("%d = %d\r\n", $a, ceil2($a, 20));
}
```

The above produces:

```
Number:    Rounded To:
0-10       0
11-30      20
31-50      40
etc.
```

This more closely simulates how `1.3=1` but `1.5=2`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this

> ceil(x/2)*2